page.navigate(url) throws com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright exception with message=net::ERR_UNEXPECTED at {url}
I have started dabbing with Playwright-Java. So part of it I wrote a simple script. While running it I came across an exception whenever I try to navigate to a url which resides within our org's network. I am connected to VPN though. The script is as below
package com.karna.maven_playwright;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserContext;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page.NavigateOptions;

public class pwtest {

    Browser browser;
    BrowserContext browserContext;
    Page page;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        Playwright pw = Playwright.create();
        browser = pw.chromium().launch(new   BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel("chrome").setHeadless(false));
        browserContext = browser.newContext();
        page = browserContext.newPage();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        NavigateOptions no = new NavigateOptions();
        no.setTimeout(0);
        page.navigate("url", no);
        String title = page.title();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Google");

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        page.close();
        browser.close();

    }
}

Exception Snippet:
PlaywrightException@41 "com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='net::ERR_UNEXPECTED at {url}
  name='Error
  stack='Error: net::ERR_UNEXPECTED at {url}
    at FrameSession._navigate (C:\Users\karnadi\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-18041136091295249458\package\lib\server\chromium\crPage.js:515:35)
    at async Frame._gotoAction (C:\Users\karnadi\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-18041136091295249458\package\lib\server\frames.js:534:28)
}
Call log:
- navigating to "{url}", waiting until "load"
"

I initially tried without passing Navigation Options. Still the same exception. Then I tried with Navigation Options
